# How do I add a delete button next to my task list?

Tags: javascript

This is what i have right now, what code do i add to make buttons next to my tasks, so with every new task there must come a remove button as well

```js
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', withClick);

function withClick(e) {
  const li = document.createElement('li')
  document.getElementById('listid').appendChild(li);
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("text-area").value))
  li.id = 'list'
  li.className = 'collection-item'
  const button = document.createElement('button')
  document.getElementById('list').appendChild(button);
  button.appendChild(document.createTextNode('x'))
  button.className = "button"
}
```

```html
<ul id="listid">
</ul>
<input id="text-area">
<button id="submit">submit</button>
```

[This is what it looks like in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvaQK.png)

Comment: I have tried that and i have that right now, but the buttons keep adding up next to each other instead of under each other attached to their own task

Comment: I edited the main comment, this is what i have right now i also provided a picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*`id` needs to be unique in HTML.*

Currently every `<li>` element you create has `id="list"`.  So when you do this:

```
document.getElementById('list')
```

Which one do you expect it to find and why?  The behavior is likely undefined, but what you're observing is that it finds the *first* one with that `id` and then stops searching.  Because why wouldn't it?  Once it finds the element with the target `id`, as far as the browser is concerned it has found the *one* target element you're looking for.

Instead of fetching the element by its `id`, you *already have* a reference to it in the `li` variable.  Just use that:

```js
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', withClick);

function withClick(e) {
  const li = document.createElement('li')
  document.getElementById('listid').appendChild(li);
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("text-area").value))
  li.className = 'collection-item'
  const button = document.createElement('button')
  li.appendChild(button); // <---- here
  button.appendChild(document.createTextNode('x'))
  button.className = "button"
}
```

```html
<ul id="listid">
</ul>
<input id="text-area">
<button id="submit">submit</button>
```

Comment: Yep that works! Thank you so much, sorry for the bad communication at first.